Nifi send metadata to Kafka topic
The task is to send some metadata to kafka topic in Nifi-pipeline.
For example, Java ProducerRecord api allow to send custom headers, which may be used as metadata container.
But in Nifi PublishKafkaRecord-processor I can't find any properties for custom headers.
Is there any way to send custom metadata message in Kafka Nifi processors ?
